# mod_rewrite, links and format in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have various links on my site which are all generated via PHP MySQL queries.
So on one page, it may give a load of results, and if click one it may take me to:

.../sector.php?county=Kent

However I have a Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^county/([^/]*)\.html$ /sector.php?county=$1 [L]
```

But still when I click on the link, I still see the above instead of :

```
http://sitename.co.uk/county/Kent
```

Am I doing something wrong?
This is the top of .htaccess file just in case it's formatted wrong, everything else works.  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^county/([^/]*)\.html$ /sector.php?county=$1 [L]
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /customers/6/c/d/sitename.co.uk/httpd.www/...
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files site.php>
require valid-user
```

... Obviously that's not the whole thing, Just he structure.

Even if I manually directed to the new link ...county/Kent i get a 404

Comment: Do you know if the host has mod_rewrite enabled for apache?

Comment: Yes they do. I wasn't sure at first but I did check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod_rewrite does not modify links that you output.  It only modifies incoming requests from one url to another.  How that url is interpreted is up to your application.  It will be up to you to get you links output in the form of href='/county/xxx'.  Only you can answer how to do this at this point because it depends on how your application is coded.

The reason you are getting a 404 when trying to go to /county/Keny is probably because you are including a .html in the match rule in your .htaccess file.   Your first example rule doesn't have it but the one in your sample .htaccess file does.

Comment: So if I click the following link:
http://site.com/sector.php?county=Kent

it would stay the same?

Or would it change to :
http://www.fulcio.co.uk/county/Kent
Have I missed the point of mod rewrite here ? :'(

Comment: It would stay the same.  mod_rewrite won't change anything in the browser.  Here is what happens...  The browser sends /county/Keny to your server. mod_rewrite intercepts it and instead calls php /sector.php?county=Kent.  The output is sent directly to the browser.  The browser doesnt even know this is happening.  It thinks it just went to /count/Kent all along.

Comment: Also, I see you updated the question with your rewrite rules and added the .html to both rules.  This will not work for the url /county/Kent.  The rule specifies the url must end in .html to match and do the rewrite.  /county/Kent does not.

Comment: Ok awesome, got it working, great help D-Rock, thanks for clarifying, but one last question. None of the images load on there, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the link url in your html.

Comment: But how, as they are all generated via php/mysql queries :/

Comment: well then you should edit your php. Otherwise it won't be possible. Go for the line the url is concatenated, it should be easy to fit. Another way would be to set a redirect on the raw url to the rewritten one - but that is a very dirty and unnecessary way to go.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this answer, but the OP says "But still when I click on the link, I still see the above instead of" which means that the link itself has not been modified.

Comment: But if I edit the PHP to create different links, how am I to pull all the information?> Surely that removes the use of POST and GET? You are suggesting that I just redo all the links and then concatenate the url to find the data?

Comment: you still have all the get params with the new urls, that is what your rewrite rule is doing. county/xyz is translated to county=xyz on your server.